# Unable to view metrics for Azure Container Instance

Tags: monitoring, azure

As per the title, when looking at my linux based azure container instance I am unable to view any metrics. I am attempting to troubleshoot some slow response times and being able to see memory/cpu/network usage would be super useful.

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-monitor) it should just be available to me.

I have tried on a different browser, and other team members are also seeing the same behaviour.

The ACI is deployed with 1CPU and 1GB Memory - it is only a test for now - but I cannot determine the appropriate size without the metrics being available to me.

The Instance has been redeployed and still nothing is available.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour?

[What i see in terms of available metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s0wo.png)